# Ajax Call return error like "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: OPTIONS " in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I am fetching some data from server using ajax on page loading. But these calls always returns error as `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: OPTIONS`. I have tried all the options I can but no use. Here is my code.

```
        var today = new Date();
        var monthYear = moment(today).format('MMM/YYYY');
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: baseUrl + 'statisticalboxes',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                'project-month': monthYear
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('statisticalboxes', ['as' => 'statisticalboxes','uses' => 'DashboardController@getStasticalBoxData']);
```

I have changed method into all other options, but no use.
When I look into the network tab, the requested url look like
`Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/nullstatisticalboxes`, but the actual one is `Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/statisticalboxes`

Comment: It seems like you are building your baseUrl using a variable with a null value.
Could you share the piece of code where you create baseUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `baseUrl` variable return `null` value.

Where you define `baseUrl`?

Define `baseUrl` variable.

--- OR ---

Use `url` like this.

```js
url: '/statisticalboxes',
```